# How to check sysdate - 1 in hibernate Restriction

Tags: hibernate

I have to get last 24 hour records in hibernate like mentioned in below oracle SQL.

```
select employee_id from employee where createTime > sysdate-1
```

i have written Restriction for above query something like below.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("createTime", "sysdate()-1"));
```

what is correct syntax for above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the way around and compare `'createTime' >= (NOW - 1 day)`.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("createTime", c.getTime());
```